# MySQL mixing Charset & Collations

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I read different articles and topics on this forum to help me setting up the charset & collation for my database. Not sure about the choices I made. I would appreciate any comments or advice.

I'm using MySQL 5.5.

The database (used with PHP) will have some datas from different languages (chinese, french, dutch, Us, spanish, arabic etc..)
I will mainly insert datas and get information from table ID'S. I won't need to full search and compare text.

So here is what I've done to create my database, I decided to use `CHARSET utf8mb4` and `COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

```
ALTER DATABASE testDB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

When I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sector (
    idSector INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sectoreName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (idSector)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4  AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

For some tables, I thought it was better to use `utf8_bin`
Ex: timezone (contain 168 047 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE timezone (
  zone_id int(10) NOT NULL,
  abbreviation varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  time_start decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  gmt_offset int(11) NOT NULL,
  dst char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  KEY idx_zone_id (zone_id),
  KEY idx_time_start (time_start)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

So basically I would like to know if I'm on the right or if I'm doing something that could lead to problems.

Comment: You know, MySQL has built-in timezone support. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html  If you reimplement it yourself, you then own the timezone updating. That's a nightmare. Don't do that unless you must. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different columns can have different character sets and/or collations, but...

- If you compare columns of different charset *or* collation (`WHERE a.x = b.y`), indexes cannot be used.
- `utf8` does not handle all of Chinese, nor does it handle some Emoji.  For those, you need utf8mb4.

On other issues...

- In `INT(5)`, the `(5)` means nothing.  Check out `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` with a range of 0..65535.
- `time_start decimal(11,0)` is strange for a time.  If it is a unix timestamp, either `TIMESTAMP` or `INT UNSIGNED` should work ok.  See also `TIME`.
- `dst char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin` -- this takes 3 bytes, because of utf8.  Perhaps you want `CHARACTER SET ascii` so it will be only 1 byte?
- InnoDB tables really should be given an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Probably `zone_id`?)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found a script on a website (https://timezonedb.com/). I agree with your comments about timezone table and I will make some change.

My main concern was about using CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci on a website that will have several languages and about mixing differents Charset.

Comment: Using utf8mb4 for all multi-lingual text on a web site is the only way to go.

Comment: (There may be other columns - country_code, postal_code, timezone, etc - that should be simply in ascii.)

Answer (score 0):

You are making good a good choice for your `sectoreName` column.  Notice one thing: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is a good collation for most language. But, for Spanish, it gets the alphabet wrong: in that language `N` and `Ñ` are considered different letters. `Ñ` appears immediately after `N` in the collating sequence. But in other European language they are considered the same letter.  So, your Spanish-language users will, when they ask for `Niña`, get back `Niña` and `Nina`. That may appear to them as a mistake. (But, they're probably used to getting this sort of thing from pan-European software applications.)

You should use `utf8mb4` as your character set throughout any new application.  So, use that instead of `utf8` in your `timezone` table. Using the `_bin` collation for your `abbreviation` column is fine.